# How to filter nested query results in visualforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

So I have this controller:

```
public class QuotastatExt {   
       public user currentuser {get; set;}      
        Quota_Stat__c qstat;      
       public List<Quota_Stat__c> qs {get;set;}

    public QuotastatExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {  
        qstat= (Quota_Stat__c) controller.getRecord ();
        currentuser= new User ();
        currentuser= [Select id, Alias, Name from User where id=:userinfo.getuserid() limit 1];     
        //qs= new List <Quota_Stat__c> ();
         qs= [Select q.Year__c, q.Total_Quota__c, q.Name, (Select Name, Vendor__c, Rep_Quota__c From Rep_Comms__r where name='CFiengo' limit 1) From Quota_Stat__c q order by name];
           system.debug (qs);
    }           
}
```

and this VF page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Quota_Stat__c" extensions="QuotastatExt">             
    <apex:dataTable value="{!qs}" var="vendor">      
         <apex:column headervalue="Vendor" value="{!vendor.name}"/>        
              <apex:repeat value="{!vendor.Rep_Comms__r}" var="rep" > 
                  <apex:column value="{!rep.Rep_Quota__c}"/>              
              </apex:repeat>                             
    </apex:dataTable>       
</apex:page>
```

Now this is what Im showing:
[image: Vendor and children]
As you can see, I have a limit of 1 in my inner query for children. 
So how do I NOT show the parent (Vendor) that dont return any children (vendor.Rep_Comms__r) records ?? Currenty, they appear with a blank in the amount column.

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take this approach.

Create a Map `repQuotaMap` which will store Name and Count of Child records.

```
public class QuotastatExt {   
    public user currentuser {get; set;}      
    Quota_Stat__c qstat;      
    public List<Quota_Stat__c> qs {get;set;}

    public Map<String, Integer> repQuotaMap {get;set;}

    public QuotastatExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {  
        qstat= (Quota_Stat__c) controller.getRecord ();
        currentuser= new User ();
        currentuser= [Select id, Alias, Name from User where id=:userinfo.getuserid() limit 1];     
        //qs= new List <Quota_Stat__c> ();
        qs= [Select q.Year__c, q.Total_Quota__c, q.Name, 
            (Select Name, Vendor__c, Rep_Quota__c From Rep_Comms__r where name='CFiengo' limit 1) 
            From Quota_Stat__c q order by name];

        repQuotaMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        for(Quota_Stat__c qsObj:qs)
        {
            List<Rep_Quota__c> lst = qsObj.Rep_Comms__r;
            repQuotaMap.put(qsObj.Name,lst.size());

        }
        system.debug (qs);
    }           
}
```

**Visualforce**

In the VFP, before populating the name, first check the count of child records taking value from the map using `<apex:outputPanel/>`:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Quota_Stat__c" extensions="QuotastatExt">             
    <apex:dataTable value="{!qs}" var="vendor">
        <apex:outputPanel redendered="{!repQuotaMap.get[vendor.name]>0}">
         <apex:column headervalue="Vendor" value="{!vendor.name}"/>        
          <apex:repeat value="{!vendor.Rep_Comms__r}" var="rep" > 
              <apex:column value="{!rep.Rep_Quota__c}"/>              
          </apex:repeat>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:dataTable>       
</apex:page>
```

You can refer my blog post [Display records with rowspan in Visualforce - Simplified Approach](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/02/display-records-with-rowspan-in.html) for this type of logic.